# {% ifchanged using two fields %}

Tags: django, django-templates

Is there a way to do the following in django?

```
{% for item in items %}
    {% ifchanged item.territory, item.price %}
        {{ item }}
    {% endifchanged %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add an `and` to the template and it will work:

```
{% for item in items %}
    {% ifchanged item.territory and item.price %}
        {{ item }}
    {% endifchanged %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4):

Although @david542 answer will work, it is not technically required to include `and`. You can simply use:

`{% ifchanged item.territory item.price %}`.

There is no boolean logic being executed, and if by chance a variable declared as `and` is used in the template (and is changing), then it would have undesirable results.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged for official documentation on `ifchanged` behavior.

Cheers!